# Why elements of GStreamer is always not in NULL state?

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

Recently I want to receive H.264 streams from UDP with tools of GStreamer+opencv in python. However, as I conduct the sentence as below:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(
    'udpsrc port=5600 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264"'
    ' ! rtph264depay'
    ' ! avdec_h264'
    ' ! videoconvert'
    ' ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

The code stuck and reported error like `Trying to dispose element avdec_h264-0, but it is in PLAYING instead of the NULL state.` And when I run the code again, the index increases by 1. Why are all the element is not in the right state of NULL?

Thank you for reading and if possible, I wonder what I should do before conduct this code. And is there any other methods for streaming pictures with H.264 coding?

Following are the full error reports when I interrupt the running:

```
(python:2946615): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:24:31.287:
Trying to dispose element avdec_h264-0, but it is in PLAYING instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.


(python:2946615): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:24:31.287:
Trying to dispose element rtph264depay0, but it is in PLAYING instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.


(python:2946615): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:24:31.287:
Trying to dispose element udpsrc0, but it is in PLAYING instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.


(python:2946615): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:24:31.287: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion '(g_atomic_int_get (&mini_object->lockstate) & LOCK_MASK) < 4' failed

(python:2946615): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:24:31.287:
Trying to dispose element pipeline0, but it is in PAUSED instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.

[ WARN:0] global /home/Users/dqy/myLibs/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (914) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline

(python:2946615): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:24:31.287:
Trying to dispose element videoconvert0, but it is in PLAYING instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.

[ WARN:0] global /home/Users/dqy/myLibs/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created

(python:2946615): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:24:31.287:
Trying to dispose element appsink0, but it is in READY instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `drop=1` to the appsink argument in your video capture line. Use [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/can-not-reconnect-with-cv2-videocapture-using-cv2-cap-gstreamer/177374/2) for reference.